# CLisp - sorting and combining two lists in quicksort

Tags: recursion, syntax, common-lisp, let, clisp

I'm trying to implement quicksort in CLisp, and so far I'm able to partition the list around a pivot. However, when I try to combine and recursively sort the sublists, I get either a stack overflow or an error with `let`, and I'm not sure what's going wrong. Here's my code:

```
(defun pivot (n xs)
  (list (getLesser n xs) (getGreater n xs))
)

(defun getLesser (m l)
  (cond
    ((null l) nil)
    ((<= m (car l)) (getLesser m (cdr l)))
    (t (cons (car l) (getLesser m (cdr l)))))
)

(defun getGreater (m l)
  (cond
    ((null l) nil)
    ((> m (car l)) (getGreater m (cdr l)))
    (t (cons (car l) (getGreater m (cdr l)))))
)


(defun quicksort (xs)
  (cond
    ((null xs) nil)
    (t
      (let (partition (pivot (car xs) xs))
        (cond
          ((null (car partition)) (cons (quicksort (cdr partition)) nil))
          ((null (cdr partition)) (cons (quicksort (car partition)) nil))
          (t (append (quicksort (car partition)) (quicksort (cdr partition)))))))))
```

My idea was to have a local variable `partition` that is a list of 2 lists, where `car partition` is the list of number less than the pivot, and `cdr partition` is the list of numbers greater than the pivot. Then, in the final `cond` construct, if there were no numbers less than the pivot I would recursively sort the 2nd list; if there were no numbers greater than the pivot I would sort the 1st list; else I would recursively sort both and append them in order. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling the file gives you hints about wrong syntax.

GNU CLISP produces these diagnostics:

```
$ clisp -q -c foo.lisp
;; Compiling file /tmp/foo.lisp ...
WARNING: in QUICKSORT in lines 20..28 : Illegal syntax in LET/LET*: (PIVOT (CAR XS) XS)
         Ignore the error and proceed
;; Deleted file /tmp/foo.fas
There were errors in the following functions:
 QUICKSORT
1 error, 1 warning
```

SBCL produces similar diagnostics:

```
$ sbcl --eval '(compile-file "foo.lisp")' --quit
This is SBCL 1.3.1.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
; compiling file "/tmp/foo.lisp" (written 08 MAY 2019 08:58:54 PM):
; compiling (DEFUN PIVOT ...)
; compiling (DEFUN GETLESSER ...)
; compiling (DEFUN GETGREATER ...)
; compiling (DEFUN QUICKSORT ...)
; file: /tmp/foo.lisp
; in: DEFUN QUICKSORT
;     (LET (PARTITION (PIVOT (CAR XS) XS))
;       (COND ((NULL (CAR PARTITION)) (CONS (QUICKSORT #) NIL))
;             ((NULL (CDR PARTITION)) (CONS (QUICKSORT #) NIL))
;             (T (APPEND (QUICKSORT #) (QUICKSORT #)))))
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   The LET binding spec (PIVOT (CAR XS) XS) is malformed.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 ERROR condition


; /tmp/foo.fasl written
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.021
```

You can then look up the expected syntax in [CLHS](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/FrontMatter/): http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/speope_letcm_letst.html

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for [`LET`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm) is *(LET BINDINGS . BODY)*, where *BINDINGS* is a list of bindings; each binding is a *(SYMBOL VALUE)* list. Alternatively, a binding can just be *SYMBOL*, which stands for *(SYMBOL NIL)*. Your code is:

```
(let (partition (pivot (car xs) xs))
  ...)
```

Let's write one binding per line and normalize all bindings as a proper list:

```
(let ((partition nil)
      (pivot (car xs) xs)))
  ...)
```

You can see that the code:

- binds `partition` to NIL
- has a malformed second binding: there are three elements, namely `pivot`, `(car xs)` and `xs`, which does not match the expected *(SYMBOL VALUE)* syntax.